# i want to divide two columns from the sam table but it is showing mw blank

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

```
Line fill rate = 
DIVIDE(
    countrows(
        filter(
            'fact_order_lines',
            'fact_order_lines'[On Time In Full] = 1 && 
            'fact_order_lines'[In Full] = 0
        )
    ),
    COUNTROWS('fact_order_lines')
)
```

want it dive and give me some reasult not blank

Answer (score 0):

`DIVIDE` will return BLANK() on division by 0.

So your `COUNTROWS('fact_order_lines')` is returning `BLANK()`.

You can provide an alternative result to `DIVIDE` so that it always returns a result. Eg: `DIVIDE( 5, 0, 0)`.

Perhaps you are after:

```
Line fill rate = 
  DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ALL('fact_order_lines'),
            'fact_order_lines'[On Time In Full] = 1 && 
            'fact_order_lines'[In Full] = 0
        )
    ),
    COUNTROWS(ALL('fact_order_lines')),
    0
  )
```

Note the `ALL(...)` around the table, which means give me the whole table without any fitlers. Or you can try `ALLSELECTED` instead of `ALL`. Can't help anymore without know more context to your question.